# gnome-tweak-tool is missing the window option

Tags: gnome, themes, window, ubuntu-tweak, gnome-tweak-tool

One ubuntu setup looks the following way in `gnome-tweak-tool`:

[image]

I'm customizing a new machine,  but the "Window" option is no longer available:

[image]

The first image is from Ubuntu 14.04, and second is from 16.04.1.

How can I bring the window option back?  Am I missing some kind of package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Window theme** setting was [removed](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool/commit/?id=4db51ee4) because it's not needed in GNOME any more. The window theme is now controlled by the GTK+ theme.